# How to enable form fields with a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am setting up a form with 11 rows 11 columns. Normally the form rows and columns should be disabled but when i click a button called "EDIT" it should enable all the form fields. It would be nice if someone help me in this case. thanks in advance

my edit button :

```
<table class="auto-style15" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style11" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px"><strong>Operation No</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style22" rowspan="2" style="width: 156px"><strong>Fixture No</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style22" rowspan="2" style="width: 55px"><strong>Rev</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style22" colspan="5"><strong>Status</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style22" rowspan="2" style="width: 59px"><strong>Storage</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style22" rowspan="2" style="width: 42px"><strong>ChecksTo Be<br />
    Done</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style22" rowspan="2" style="width: 154px"><strong>Remarks</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="width: 70px; height: 25px">
    <input name="oprno1" type="text" style="width: 70px" /></td>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="height: 25px; width: 156px">
    <input name="fixno1" style="width: 150px" type="text" /></td>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="height: 25px; width: 55px">
    <input name="rev1" style="width: 50px" type="text" /></td>

<input name="Button1" type="button" value="EDIT" disabled class="auto-style12" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right what you want, is to enable or disable controls on a form ... This issue has been debated here and it was answered. Kindly see if it is what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/vGc5P/1/

```
$().ready(function() {


$('#clicker').click(function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr({
                'disabled': 'disabled'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});

Question
[Script to enable/disable input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835165/script-to-enable-disable-input-elements)

Comment: hello thanks but colud you please see my code once again, i had enter in my question..

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="EDIT" disabled class="auto-style12" />
<script>
$('.auto-style12').click(function(){
    $('#textfield-id').removeAttr('disabled');
})
</script>
```

with jQuery

Comment: thank you!! is I need to specify any id for my table forms and buttons

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery 1.6+**

You can enable the fields by setting `.prop('disabled', false);`.

```
$('input').prop('disabled', false);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

```
$('input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

**The function**

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
    $('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

You can target `input` and `textarea` fields within your table and give it a class or ID.

```
$('table#edit input, table#edit textarea').prop('disabled', false);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sGCxN/)**

Comment: Add your HTML and JQuery to the question.

Comment: could you please help me now, i had entered my code too

Comment: @ShryVishnuMurugesan It's a bit unclear what you are asking, as you have updated the question multiple times. You can't click the "EDIT" button to start with if you have disabled it. Please explain why my answer doesn't solve your problem.