# How do I disable a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have numerous html input tags, which takes the user input and post it to a variable, code :

```
<form method = "post" action=""select.php> 
    <input id="nol" style="width: 280px;" type="text" name="searchdisease" placeholder="type diagnosis one">
    <input id="nol" style="width: 280px;" type="text" name="searchdisease1" placeholder="type diagnosis two">
    <input id="nol" style="width: 280px;" type="text" name="searchdisease2" placeholder="type diagnosis three">
</form>
```

then this variable i append it to SQL  query to retrieve data LIKE user input code:

```
$search_disease = $_POST['searchdisease'];
$search_disease1 = $_POST['searchdisease1'];
$search_disease2 = $_POST['searchdisease2'];

$query="SELECT diagnosis FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%$search_disease%'";
$result= $con->query($query);
$query1="SELECT diagnosis FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%$search_disease1%'";
$result1= $con->query($query1);
$query2="SELECT diagnosis FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%$search_disease2%'";
$result2= $con->query($query2);
```

, then echo the results to a select tag.
code:

```
<select id="disease" style="width: 40%;" name="tdisease">
   <option value="">Select Disease</option>
   <?php
       while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
   ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
   <?php } ?> 
</select>
<select id="disease" style="width: 40%;" name="tdisease1">
   <option value="">Select Disease</option>
   <?php
       while ($row=$result1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
   ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
  <?php } ?> 
</select>
<select id="disease" style="width: 40%;" name="tdisease2">
     <option value="">Select Disease</option>
     <?php
         while ($row=$result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
     ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
     <?php } ?> 
</select>
```

So i want to know how can i use JavaScript to disable or hide the select tags when the user input is empty?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also shouldn't use the same `ID` multiple times. `ID`'s should be unique. Could you also show where the `input` is that might be empty.... since this would be relevant to your question.

Comment: You can't use same id for different element.

Comment: i have not tried anything, maybe i should have mentioned that i do not know JavaScript nor JQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script to enable/disable input elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835165/script-to-enable-disable-input-elements) and/or [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Comment: or if you rather use jQuery, you can get examples here ► [https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add event listener on your tags, which will add attribute to selected one "disabled".

It will look like:
`const target = document.querySelector('<yourtag>');
 target.value.length > 0 ? 'it is ok' : target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: okay before i disable it, i want to check if it has a value or not then if it does not contain any data then disable it, how can i do that first?

Comment: As I said, with this line `target.value.length > 0` you'll get the result. If value length less than 0, means that it has no characters, you do `target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')`. I've used ternary operator to keep code clean and simple.

Comment: i am trying to disable the select tag if user input is empty not the input field as such, but the select tag and html tag are on different forms.

Comment: and you can do it by this code: `const selectTag = document.querySelector('<selectTag>');
const userInput = document.querySelector('<userInput>');
 userInput.value.length > 0 ? 'it is ok' : selectTag.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: i have been trying this but got no luck, please bear with me, i do not know JavaScript that much, but do i replace  ('<selectTag>') with id of the tag? or just leave it as it is? and should place it on form which have input fields or where the select tag is?

Answer (score -1):

ID should be different for every inputs.then,

```
var val=$('#id-of-element').val;
```

check as: `if(val==" ")` or `if(val==null)`
it will be blank when the input is nothing.

you can use below line of code to disable an item:

```
document.getElementById("id-of-selected-element").disabled="true";
```

To hide:

```
document.getElementById("id-of-selected-element").style.display="none";
```

Comment: okay before i disable it, i want to check if it has a value or not then if it does not contain any data then disable it, how can i do that first?

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: okay it did nor work, i do not if i did not do it correctly or what, but just so you know, the input tag which i want to check its value its on a different form, on a different page and the select tag as well

Comment: give a name to the tag you want to get. submit the form in first page,  get the value of select tag by it's name attribute in second page.  refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted